# How can i invoke a function of one object to another object

Tags: javascript

I have two .js files login.js and database.js. How can i invoke a function from database.js to login.js? Is it possible?

database.js

```
var Database = function(key, value)
{

        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;

        this.getStorage = function() 
        {

        }

        this.setStorage = function() 
        {

        }
}

    var db = new Database();
```

login.js

```
var Login = function(database) 
{   
    this.database = database;
} 

var login = new Login();
```

So i wanna call getStorage or setStorage method to login.js is it possible? And how?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You have to include first the database.js then login.js . This way you can use the fonction in database.js in login.js :

```
<head>
     <!--include  first database.js then login.js  -->
     <script src="database.js"></script>
     <script src="login.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can i then call that method in login.js for example this.setStorage if you could help me?

Comment: you have instantiated in database.js a database ojbect  db. So you can use like this the fuction : db.setStorage()  in login.js

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to instantiate your database object (which you have already done in database.js) and pass that into login:

`var login = new Login(db);`